# What ExternalProgrammer types are supported?

Tags: microcontroller-kit

Does anyone know how to determine what external programmers are supported by the new Microcontroller Kit functionality? The syntax below seems like it should work, but it does not.

```
Needs["MicrocontrollerKit`"];

EntityValue["ExternalProgrammer", "Entities"]

(* Missing["UnknownType","ExternalProgrammer"] *)
```

Comment: Why should that work? I'm not sure how many people are familiar enough with that package to know why it would be hooked into the `Entity` framework.

Comment: It is the same syntax they use in the examples to list the supported targets. It does work for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This list is not maintained by the Microcontroller Kit because it's essentially a duplicate of what is listed under programmer-id in https://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/user-manual/avrdude_4.html. In addition to being a duplicate, such a list also has the potential to get out of sync.